# Magento Unable to restore database

Tags: database

I need urgent restore of Magento DB. I have an sql file exported from PHPMYADMIN, I am unable to restore this file from command line, it give an error Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'.

I am frantic, should I drop Magento DB and restore the PHPMADMIN generated backup?

I have disabled foriegn key restraints per this Wiki
http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/restoring_a_backup_of_a_magento_database

Any help appreciated

Comment: Basically, drop the database, create the database, import into freshly cleansed, empty database. However, this database must be exclusively used by the Magento installation and the restored data not be borked with actual duplicate garbage in it. If borked, there is a Magento database repair utility to cleanse garbage, check structure, etc. Plus, you quickly learn to distrust database dumps done through phpMyAdmin. The extra gui overhead can run out of time and memory, leaving you with a partial backup.

Comment: @FiascoLabs What the heck does "borked" mean?

Comment: When your data gets translated by the Swedish Chef on the Muppets. Data corruption of any kind. Dates back to the days of nntp for the equivalent of an earlier generation's FUBAR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above,I dropped the database, recreated it and re-imported. This led to a few problems that I am still wrestling with. For Magento backup just use the build in Magento backup tool, you can then scp the backup file to local if needed. This way all the database dependencies are preserved which is not the case with Phpmyadmin backup.

Comment: I use mysqldump from the command line and it always works fine for me. I don't use phpMyAdmin because my databases are too large - the script could time out, plus it forces me to download the entire output file (at least in older version of PMA) rather than save it on the disk. I've set up a nightly cron job that backs up my entire db using mysqldump.

Comment: Phpmyadmin is a recipe for disaster here. We exceeded its capacity early on and found even if we extended the db upload size and timeouts, it still would die mid backup, especially when you needed it the most.  Mysqldump for the win always. Full, efficient backups and then scp download from the server. Allows for full, efficent mysql import after dropping and recreating the db every time. And so far, no messing with foreign key checks.